# Guest OS (Windows 10) cannot connect to Internet but all apps (including Edge) can

Tags: windows, networking, macos, vmware-fusion

I have MacOS Catalina (but had same issue under Mojave).  I am running Fusion 8.5.10 and Windows 10 Home version 1803.  I use this purely to run Metatrader 4 - which connects perfectly, as does Edge and all other applications *except* Windows itself.

Windows Status => Network Status shows "Not connected" but under "Ethernet", both available connections show "connected".

So now I cannot get Windows Updates -- "We couldn't check for updates, because you aren't connected to the Internet" (which incidentally shows that I last connected 1/17/2019 so it clearly worked up to some unknown event).

The system tray shows a red "X" at the Network and Internet settings icon - and hovering brings up "Not connected - no connections are available" yet bible-clicking on this icon brings up one (not 2) connections, which happens to be Ethernet0 - which says "Connected"!

If I open a command prompt I can ping the default gateway and internet IPs such as Google.

Now, clearly this is no huge issue - but I am at my wits end trying to understand what is going on! Anyone got ANY ideas?

Incidentally but possibly not related, I also cannot get audio to work on the guest OS, even though I have selected Bose USB Audio as the Output Device under "Connect Sound Card"

Answer (score 0):

The only supported version of VMWare Fusion on Catalina is 11.5

Fusion 8 was only supported up to Sierra

Table from VMWare KB - [Supported host operating systems for VMware Fusion and VMware Fusion Pro](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2088571)

[image]

That would suggest your issues would be solved by upgrading.
With such as Fusion & Parallels, 'unsupported' usually means 'proven not to work'.

Comment: Very good suggestion. I downloaded a demo version of Fusion 11.5 and ran up my original guest OS and saw the same issues.  I then created a new virtual machine (a fresh ISO of Windows 10) under Fusion 11.5 and this ran perfectly. I reverted back to Fusion 8.5 and again, created a new VM - and again, this ran perfectly.  I think it is fairly safe to say that the issues I was experiencing lay within the original VM and as I no longer need anything from it, I am now running quite happily on Fusion 11.5, Windows 10 Home version 1903 and switched from MT4 to MT5.

Comment: Interesting. Glad you got it sorted anyway :)