# How to enable screen recording on VMWare Ubuntu virtual machine running on Mac Catalina?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have previously been able to run Ubuntu through VMWare (version Version 8.5.10) on my Mac with no problems. However, since updating to Catalina, my Ubuntu VM screen is blank and I can only see it through the VM library preview and operate it with the keyboard, which does mean I can use the terminal.

After a lot of searching online, it seems that I need to allow my Ubuntu VM to access my Macs screen recording (as shown under Settings > Security& Privacy > Privacy), which should be requested with a popup message.

I am wondering if there is a way to force VMWare to make this request, perhaps from my Ubuntu terminal? I'm hoping this will allow me to view my Ubuntu VM as normal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported version of VMWare Fusion on Catalina is 11.5

Fusion 8 was only supported up to Sierra

Table from VMWare KB - [Supported host operating systems for VMware Fusion and VMware Fusion Pro](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2088571)

[image]

That would suggest your issues would be solved by upgrading.
With such as Fusion & Parallels, 'unsupported' usually means 'proven not to work'.

Copied from my own answer at https://superuser.com/a/1494673/347380